# Can we add numpy object pulp objective function

Tags: python, numpy, pulp

I came across following code:

```
from pulp import *
import numpy as np
prob = LpProblem("lp_prob", LpMinimize)
decision_variables = LpVariable.dicts('x', range(5))
prob += np.sum(decision_variables.values())
```

When I tried same code on my machine, it gave following error on last line:

```
TypeError: Can only add LpConstraintVar, LpConstraint, LpAffineExpression or True objects
```

Cant I add numpy array to `LpProblem`. Now I am guessing if the given code is incorrect? Also is there any other way / version (of python and/or numpy and/or pulp) in which adding numpy object to `LpProblem` works?

Answer (score 0):

1. `decision_variables` is not a numpy array. It is a dictionary and that's why you can do `decision_variables.values()`.
2. `decision_variables.values()` is not a numpy array either, it's a `dictvalues` object.
3. the result of `np.sum` is not a numpy array. *When applied to a numpy array* it should return a scalar value. But for a `dictvalues` object it does nothing (no sum, at least).
4. I'm not sure why you would need to use `np.sum` at all here.

In pulp, the sum of a set of pulp variables (list, dictvalues, dictkeys, etc.) is done with the `lpSum` function (https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/pulp.html#pulp.lpSum).

`prob += lpSum(decision_variables.values())`